# Plotly Scatter plot with animation and Images instead of dots

Tags: python, plotly

I have dataframe `dmg` with some data by weeks, also every dot has own path with png image.

Example:

| ww | type | pawn | img | pic | wr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-08 | dmg | Cry | path1.png | 3 | -9 |
| 2022-08-08 | dmg | Ro | path5.png | 1 | -11 |
| 2022-08-08 | dmg | Dem | path4.png | 31 | -5 |
| 2022-08-08 | dmg | Mag | path3.png | 0 | -36 |
| 2022-08-08 | dmg | Rea | path2.png | 1 | -6 |
| 2022-08-15 | dmg | Cry | path1.png | 6 | 9 |
| 2022-08-15 | dmg | Ro | path5.png | 5 | -1 |
| 2022-08-15 | dmg | Dem | path4.png | 23 | 0 |
| 2022-08-15 | dmg | Mag | path3.png | 5 | -5 |
| 2022-08-15 | dmg | Rea | path2.png | 19 | 22 |

If I have 1 week, I can make this graph

```
fig = go.Figure()
for i, x in enumerate(dmg['pic']):
    fig.add_layout_image(
            dict(
                source=Image.open(dmg['img'].iloc[i]),
                xref="x",
                yref="y",
                x=x,
                y=dmg['wr'].iloc[i],
                sizex=2,
                sizey=2
            )
    )
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[0, 100], yaxis_range=[-20,20])

fig.show()
```

But I want to have several weeks and make this:

```
fig = px.scatter(dmg, x='pic', y='wr', animation_frame="ww")
```

How to combine these scripts to update layouts and place png images on every frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- each frame has a layout.  Add the images to the appropriate frame layout
- have used **kaggle** images to demonstrate.  Substitute with your own
- key if `groupby()` data frame with same column that was used to generate animation
- finally add images of first frame into default layout of figure

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests, io, base64
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
from PIL import Image

# fmt: off
# download some images to demonstrate
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/anzhemeng/nfl-team-logos"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
# fmt: on
zfile.extractall("nfl-logos")

# URI encode an image
def b64image(path):
    b = io.BytesIO()
    im = Image.open(path)
    im.save(b, format="PNG")
    b64 = base64.b64encode(b.getvalue())
    return "data:image/png;base64," + b64.decode("utf-8")


dmg = pd.DataFrame(
    **{
        "columns": ["ww", "type", "pawn", "img", "pic", "wr"],
        "data": [
            ["2022-08-08", "dmg", "Cry", "path1.png", 3, -9],
            ["2022-08-08", "dmg", "Ro", "path5.png", 1, -11],
            ["2022-08-08", "dmg", "Dem", "path4.png", 31, -5],
            ["2022-08-08", "dmg", "Mag", "path3.png", 0, -36],
            ["2022-08-08", "dmg", "Rea", "path2.png", 1, -6],
            ["2022-08-15", "dmg", "Cry", "path1.png", 6, 9],
            ["2022-08-15", "dmg", "Ro", "path5.png", 5, -1],
            ["2022-08-15", "dmg", "Dem", "path4.png", 23, 0],
            ["2022-08-15", "dmg", "Mag", "path3.png", 5, -5],
            ["2022-08-15", "dmg", "Rea", "path2.png", 19, 22],
        ],
    }
)

# encode images to URI encoded images, use NFL logos as don't have images used in question
img_map = {
    img: b64image(b64)
    for img, b64 in zip(
        dmg["img"].unique(), Path.cwd().joinpath("nfl-logos").glob("*.png")
    )
}

dmg["img_source"] = dmg["img"].map(img_map)

fig = px.scatter(dmg, x="pic", y="wr", animation_frame="ww")
# iterate over frames and groups and add images to layout of each frame
# NB groupby() same column as animation column
for (i, g), fr in zip(dmg.groupby("ww"), fig.frames):
    l = {
        "images": [
            dict(
                x=r["pic"],
                y=r["wr"],
                source=r["img_source"],
                xref="x",
                yref="y",
                sizex=10,
                sizey=10,
                xanchor="center",
                yanchor="middle",
            )
            for _, r in g.iterrows()
        ]
    }
    fr.update(layout=l)

# add images in first frame to default layout
for i in fig.frames[0].layout.images:
    fig.add_layout_image(i)

fig
```